# How to read more than 256 columns from an excel file (2007 format) using OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, limit

I'm trying to import a excel file with more than 256 columns using OLEDB in C#. I tried all kinds of things, but it doesn't seem to be possible to read more than 256 columns from a excel (2007 format) file. I'm wondering if it's a bug or I'm simply missing something. Here is the connection string I used:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation on the Jet OLEDB driver. One solution that might work (i.e. I haven't tried it) would be to breakup the sheet into named ranges that are no wider than 255 columns and query for each of those separately (e.g. `Select * From RangeName`) and then merge the results into a single DataTable.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Can you propose another solution other than breaking the sheet into named ranges? Thanks

Comment: @HassanMokdad - Yes. You need to use an Excel engine other than OLEDB. E.g., ExcelWriter, EPPlus, NPOI. These three are free. There are other engines made from companies like SyncFusion or Aspose which cost money but all can handle building sheets larger than 256 columns. Another choice is to use OpenXml.

Answer (score 0):

Import an excel file with more than 256 columns using Oledb is not possible. Oledb will only return first 255 columns.

Please use ExcelDataReader DLL. It is a Lightweight open source library used for reading Microsoft Excel files in .NET.

here is an ondrive link for code reference : cheers!!

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=4B1F6C3E92F6522C%21257&cid=4B1F6C3E92F6522C&group=0&parId=4B1F6C3E92F6522C%21125&authkey=%21AMbQad-vwusjl-4&o=OneUp