# c# How to clear oledbconnection cache, multiple excel queries erroring out

Tags: c#, excel

Sorry for the vague title but I'm not sure how best to word it.

Basically, the issue that I'm having is that I initially was using an oledbconnection in C# to initiate a connection to a spreadsheet, query it, and load the results into a .net datatable. Unfortunately, it maxes out at 255 fields which I have around 600.

So, what I did instead was I created a dataset and tried to load 4 separate data tables with separate queries. Now for some reason, what's crazy to me is, if I load lets say, the first data table with 190 fields, and then I go on to query the spreadsheet again, if I go over that 250 mark (which I'd have 60 left), I get the following error:

---

An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

### Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

If I reduce the amount of fields in the second table to equal less than 250 though, it works. Anyway, is there a way that I can somehow clear the cache of the oledbconnection to somehow drop the first 190 fields or whatever is holding the result of the excel query so I can move on to the next? I tried doing a data adapter dispose but that didn't work, same issue. If I do a connection.dispose, I have to re-initialize the connection anyway. Is there a way I can still do this without having to drop the connection? Code below:

```
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(Settings.ExcelCN);

        OleDbCommand fillT1 = new OleDbCommand(Settings.Excel_Proj_Select_1, cnn);
        OleDbCommand fillT2 = new OleDbCommand(Settings.Excel_Proj_Select_2, cnn);
        OleDbCommand fillT3 = new OleDbCommand(Settings.Excel_Proj_Select_3, cnn);
        OleDbCommand fillT4 = new OleDbCommand(Settings.Excel_Proj_Select_4, cnn);
        OleDbCommand updateCnt = new OleDbCommand(Settings.Excel_Update_Count_Select, cnn);

        cnn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(fillT1);
        OleDbDataAdapter adp2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(fillT2);
        OleDbDataAdapter adp3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(fillT3);
        OleDbDataAdapter adp4 = new OleDbDataAdapter(fillT4);

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();

        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

        adp1.Fill(dt1);
        ds1.Tables.Add(dt1);

        adp2.Fill(dt2);
        ds1.Tables.Add(dt2);

        adp3.Fill(dt3);
        ds1.Tables.Add(dt3);

        adp4.Fill(dt4);
        ds1.Tables.Add(dt4);

        int rowcount = updateCnt.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Does constructing, using, and disposing the data adapters sequentially work?

Comment: I can try giving that shot.- Actually no, it doesn't I did try that, unfortunately same issue.

Comment: Maybe this can be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766466/how-to-read-more-than-256-columns-from-an-excel-file-2007-format-using-oledb

Comment: That does seem like odd behavior.  Nothing obviously wrong with the code that I see.  Is there a reason you don't want to just use multiple connections?  Too slow?

Comment: @Zer0 I just figured it'd be bad practice to repeat opening a connection more than once is all. I may just have to try that.

Comment: Usually that error with OleDb means that something is wrong in the column names. (or table name). Do you have "headers" in the sheet? Do you write the column names (headers) in your queries?

Comment: @Steve Yes it usually does, but I tested it a bunch of different ways to cross-verify that wasn't the issue. You can swap column names in, out, however, and it works until you get more than the 255th. I experienced the same thing if you select a range. I found that people said you can bypass this limit by doing a select * from a specific range, but it doesn't work, just tells you there's an error retrieving the data. I guess I will try the 4 different connections.

Comment: So just in case anyone was wondering, I sort of figured out what the issue is. When you open the oledbcommand with the spreadsheet, it must only read in 255 columns. It just pretends the ones beyond that do not exist. 

I tested all afternoon and eventually got to a point where if you even select 1 column from the page, as long as it's beyond the 255th column, it pretends it doesn't exist and won't find it.

How crazy is that? Anyway, I think I will just have to code this using NPOI. I used it once before but it's a little bit more involved than just doing a straight select.