# VB.NET - Importing more than 255 columns from Excel to a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently using OleDb to import excel data into a DataGridView, but I am having trouble adding more than 255 columns into the DGV (I need to add more because I need to show full years worth of columns, plus a number of data columns which are needed - so I need to show at least 370 columns).

Code:

```
ReadOnly _dataFile As String = Path.Combine(_path, "DataStorage\Numbers.xlsx")
ReadOnly _connection As String = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _dataFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
Private Const sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM [Numbers$] WHERE NOT [Status] = 'Deleted'"

Dim objDs As New DataSet
Dim objDt As New DataTable
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
objDs.Tables.Add(objDt)
Dim objConn As String = _connection
conn.ConnectionString = objConn
Dim objDa As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn)
objDa.Fill(objDt)
MainDataGridView.DataSource = objDt.DefaultView
MainDataGridView.Sort(MainDataGridView.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Does anybody know what I can do differently here to import more than 255 columns into the DataGridView?

Comment: It looks like the limitation reported in [How to read more than 256 columns from an excel file (2007 format) using OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766466/how-to-read-more-than-256-columns-from-an-excel-file-2007-format-using-oledb) still applies. You could try a third-party Excel file-reading library - search google etc. for ".net third-party Excel library" and find one with licence terms that meet your requirements.

Comment: Some options: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/09/reading-excel-files-in-net-core/

Comment: just a suggestion - maybe it would make more sense to break it up into different forms/views rather than throwing it all in 370 columns?

Comment: @kshkarin - Thats not possible unfortunately as all of the yearly data in the DGV needs to be visible to the user - turns out using a third party Excel library is the only speed efficient way of making this possible.