# Excel - VBA CopyFromRecordset Field limit 256

Tags: sql, excel, ado

I'm trying to copy data from some excel xlsx files via ADO to my excel file. The data files have 282 columns, but I've just found out the limitation of fields is only up to 256.

Does anybody know if there is a way to extend that limit?

Just in case I'm using Office 365. Part of the code below:

```
    MyConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                         SourceFile & _
                        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
                        
    Set MyCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    MyCon.Open ConnectionString:=MyConnectionString
    
    Set MyRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
 
    i = 6
    For Each Ticker In TickerArray
        SQLString = "SELECT * FROM [Dashboard$A:JV] where Símbolo = '" & Ticker & "'"
        
        MyRecordset.Open Source:=SQLString, _
                         ActiveConnection:=MyCon, _
                         CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, _
                         Options:=adCmdText

       Debug.Print MyRecordset.Fields.Count
```

Result of Debug.Print MyRecordset.Fields.Count = 255

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766466/how-to-read-more-than-256-columns-from-an-excel-file-2007-format-using-oledb

Answer (score 0):

The same issue exists for rows as well.  I have a Power Pivot model with > 350 Measures.  When I run Bertrand d'Arbonneau's otherwise excellent Power Pivot Utilities, the CopyFromRecordset line only copies over the first 256 measures.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB providers have a built-in limit of 255 fields.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a link to documentation that describes the limit.